What kinds of optimisations can produce a const parameter?
I always wondered if it is a good practice to have always prefer const parameters when I can ? On one side you tell the compiler that this variable won't be mutated inside the function's scope so it can do optimizations under the hood, but on the other hand it does not affect the caller since arguments are passed by copy, so it can make the code bloated with consts everywhere and thus less readable.
Does someone know what kinds of optimisations are done under the hood by compilers on const parameters ? Can it optimize by passing the variable as reference without copying it for example ? Are there concurrency implications that we should be aware of ? (eg. when mutating the variable in another thread while the function is running).
Are the pros worth the cons ?

You can declare it in the function declaration (e.g. in the shared header file) without the const to avoid clutter, since as you write, it is irrelevant for the caller, but you can still declare it with the const in the function definition and it will still be compatible with the declaration.

Also the compiler knows if the parameter is being modified or not, so the const is really only there for the programmer.

And the same thing applies to variables of course.

You also asked whether the compiler could optimize the function call if the parameter is declared const and the answer is no, because the const is ignored for the caller.

@IanAbbott const gives the compiler more information than it otherwise would have. For example it can avoid reloading the value after a call to a function taking a pointer to the variable, even if the definition of the function isn't visible.

@user17732522 I think you are referring to parameters that are pointers to const types (e.g. const int *param), but I think the question is about parameter types being declared const (e.g. const int param or int * const param).

@IanAbbott No, I mean const on the parameter or local variable. For example here the return value can be constant-folded to 1 with const but not without. (No idea why Clang isn't doing it though.) On the other hand const-qualifying the pointer has no implications for optimizations. Only top-level const on definitions can influence optimization.

@user17732522 OK, I get what you mean regarding allowing optimizations that would result in UB if violated.

Didn't know about the fact that you could declare without const and implement with const, I assume that the best approach is to use const as much as possible (when it makes sense) for the implementations and remove the const parameters from the declarations then ?

@EricPostpischil Did you mean "In void foo(int x) { bar(&x); }, the compiler does not know..."? Otherwise the comment wouldn't make sense.

const is not only a message to the compiler. It also informs the developers that the value of the variable should not change.

@user694733: Yes, the first declaration of foo in my comment should have int x. I will re-enter it.

@IanAbbott: Re “Also the compiler knows if the parameter is being modified or not”: Not so. In void foo(int x) { bar(&x); }, the compiler does not know whether bar changes x, even if bar is declared void bar(const int *). But if foo is defined with void foo(const int x) { … }, then the compiler may assume bar does not change x.

From C17 6.5.2.2 paragraph 2:

… Each argument shall have a type such that its value may be assigned to an object with the unqualified version of the type of its corresponding parameter.

From C17 6.7.6.3 paragraph 15:

… (In the determination of type compatibility and of a composite type, each parameter declared with function or array type is taken as having the adjusted type and each parameter declared with qualified type is taken as having the unqualified version of its declared type.)

This effectively means that qualifiers such as const in the immediate type of the function parameter are ignored by the caller, and are only meaningful to the called function itself, where they serve the same role as qualifiers in local variables.
It also means that these function declarations are compatible:
int foo(int a);
int foo(const int a);

If the parameter is declared const in the function definition, then the compiler can treat the parameter the same way as a variable defined const with an initializer:
int foo(const int a)
{
    const int b = 42;
    /* this is not a great example! */
    return a + b;
}

When declaring the function in a shared header file, I would recommend declaring the parameter without the qualifier, because it is not relevant to callers of the function.

Are you sure the "C17 6.7.2.3 paragraph 16" is correct? In my document (admittedly it's only C17 draft N2176) the sentence is in 6.7.6.3 Function declarators (including prototypes) paragraph 15.

I think there's more to it than just qualifiers. Neither gcc nor clang assumes that a pointed-at variable remains unmodified after a function call, even if the declared object is int but I cast its address to const bananas_t* as used by the function. Supposedly the compiler isn't free to assume that inside the function, the pointer isn't converted back to an int*, which may be used to modify the original object. The only way to prevent such assumptions is to declare the caller object as const int.

We should get used to refer to C23. It has finally been published (Oct 31st).

@user694733 Thanks for the correction. Not sure why I typed it in wrong!

@Lundin Correct, although I'm not sure what bananas have to do with it! I'm really focussing on a different part of the question than @user17732522. I'm focussing on the effect of const parameters on optimizations of calls to the functions, whereas user17732522 is focussing on optimizations on const variables in general. And I'm advocating for a mix and match approach to reduce bloat.

@nielsen True, but I don't have a copy, and I'm not sure of the exact differences between the published standard and the various C23 and C2y drafts, although I do know that the section numbering in the published standard matches the N3299 C2y draft but does not match the earlier C2y and C23 drafts.

@IanAbbott bananas_t as in strict aliasing does not have anything to do with it, since it's some wildly incompatible type.

And regarding C23... I'm pretty certain they will have to publish a big TC because there are so many errors in it. Until then I don't blame anyone for sticking with C17.

There are optimization pros to using top-level const on variable definitions where it is valid (anywhere that is a definition, not only in parameters in a function definition).
The top-level const on a variable causes any attempt to modify the object's value to have undefined behavior. As a consequence the compiler can deduce that its value will never change, even if a pointer to it escapes to some unknown function.
Without that, any such pointer escape requires the compiler to have to assume that the object's value may be changed by any unknown call. This is even if the function takes a pointer-to-const, because unlike the top-level const in a definition, that const has no meaning for optimization and exists purely for the benefit of the programmer to reason about the code and avoid semantic mistakes.
I do not see any cons, except that code sometimes gets harder to read with more keyword boiler-plate. There may be a slight risk that something is accidentally defined with const that actually is modified, causing UB. However, if the code is written with const correctness in mind, that should be unlikely. Explicit conversions are always a potential risk for casting away const qualifiers in violation of const correctness.
